# Qt смена шрифта

Tags: c++, qt

Программирую софт на OpenSuse с фиксированым шрифтом. При запуске софта на другом дистрибутиве, к примеру на Ubuntu, выстовляется другой шрифт. Как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно задать шрифт для всего приложения при помощи [`QApplication::setFont`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont).

Или можно пойти дальше и задать сразу весь стиль при помощи [`QApplication::setStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle), чтоб неизменным было все приложение, а не только шрифт.

Если нужна большая гибкость в настройке стиля, можно подробно его описать на css-подобном языке и задать его при помощи [`QApplication::setStyleSheet`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop)